# three js clickable cube texture

Tags: three.js

I am new on the JavaScript and HTML. I am on learning process. I successfully made a cube and textured it. I also want to add different html link to open pages in "iframe".

I used the example of http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html

This is what I did http://olcaysahin.com/pages/cube.html

If anyone knows any tutorial or similar approach to make each face clickable, appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html.

The from variable `intersects`, you can determine which face was clicked on from either the `faceIndex` or the face `normal`.

Comment: @Hamdi Please ask a specific question in a new post. Thanks.

Comment: I am asking about this question. We added your code but intersects.length equals to zero.

Comment: @Hamdi You will have to provide your source code. You are most likely to get help if you provide a live example.

Comment: Thank you. If you look at to source file in page -> http://www.olcaysahin.com/pages/cube.html you will see cube.js referenced. Please debug the page, add breakpoint in onMouseDown method in cube.js. No matter where you click, the variable `**intersects**` always comes empty.

Comment: `ray.intersectObjects()` takes an array as an arg. Try `ray.intersectObject()`, without the `s`.

Comment: Thank you @Hamdi and WestLangley. It works perfect. clickable function for the each cube face determined by the the normals. For reference just in case somebody needed it as follows: 'if(intersects[0].face.normal.x==0 && intersects[0].face.normal.y==0 &&intersects[0].face.normal.z==-1){window.top.location="www.google.com";'

Comment: @Hamdi Please do not forget to "accept" answers that you find acceptable. :-)

Comment: I voted up for your answer :) Let's ask @olcaysah if he accepts